# Issue in changing the visiblity of buttons inside OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, button, audio

Below is code for playing audio in my project.When i click on play button it changes to pause button  and I am playing audio through init() method inside my Application class.The issue i am facing is that after clicking on play button it takes few seconds(5-10 seconds) after which play button changes to pause.But it should immediately change to pause button as my first statement inside onClick() is `holder.pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`. However if i comment out init method call line `ProjectApplication.getInstance().init(mCtxt, lMoment.getProjectMediaLoc(), holder.lVisualizerView, lAudioProgressBar,holder.Image,holder.Image2);` then it immediately changes to pause button but init method is required for playing audio.If i use postDelayed() method and call init() method after 2 seconds then it works as expected .But I fail to understand why init() method is creating problem in changing the visiblity of play and pause buttons as init method() is called after changing the visiblity.

```
holder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    holder.pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    ProjectApplication.getInstance().init(mCtxt, lMoment.getProjectMediaLoc(), holder.lVisualizerView, lAudioProgressBar,holder.play,holder.pause);

                    notifyDataSetChanged();





                }

            });
```

ProjectApplication.java

```
 public void init(Context mCtxt,String aAudioUrl, final VisualizerView mVisulizerView,final ProgressBar lAudioProgressBar,final ImageView play,final ImageView pause  )
    {

        lAudioProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mProjectPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(mCtxt, Uri.parse(aAudioUrl));
      mProjectPlayer.setLooping(false);
        mProjectPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                Log.e("msg","start");
                mProjectPlayer.start();

                mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                lAudioProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mProjectPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       pause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mVisulizerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        ProjectApplication.getInstance().cleanUp(mVisulizerView);
                        HomeFragment.projectListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to move the call to 'init' to an AsyncTask.  It's blocking the UI thread.  I know it seems like it should finish updating the UI before it moves on to the next statement, but I can't offer a better explanation.  Perhaps someone who knows more about android guts will do better.